# React Native: How to implement to show/hide certain features in the app based on user subscription plan

Tags: react-native

I am implementing payments in react-native. I have used stripe sdk to show the payments screen. After the payment is completed, I get a webhook from stripe. Now, I want to show hide certain components/features of the app based on the selected user plan. One way of doing that is conditional rendering, but apart from conditional rendering, what are the other effective and ideal ways to solve this problem.

I tried conditional rendering and it works, but since my application is huge, I do not think this is the ideal way of doing this.

Comment: If you are using react-navigation you could do something like the auth flow [example](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) and make some screens only accessible to those with the right subscription plan